# UWP Gamepad.Gamepads is empty even though a controller is connected

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, xbox, gamepad

I'm currently working on a UWP app and I want to be able to take input from a wireless xbox controller however, whenever I try and access it in my code, I get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'`.

I know that the controller is connected because it shows up in my bluetooth devices and I can use it in Steam Big Picture and in games without a problem. I'm trying to access the controller using this code:

```
var controller = Gamepad.Gamepads.First();
var reading = controller.GetCurrentReading();
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to take input from a wireless xbox controller however, whenever I try and access it in my code, I get the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'.

From [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad):

> the gamepad list is initally empty and will not list gamepads even if they are already connected. After a short period this will return a complete list of gamepads.

For this scenario, you could list all connected gamepads through the [`Gamepad.GamepadAdded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad#Windows_Gaming_Input_Gamepad_GamepadAdded) event.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Gamepad.GamepadAdded += Gamepad_GamepadAdded;
}

private void Gamepad_GamepadAdded(object sender, Gamepad e)
{
    var controller = Gamepad.Gamepads?.First(); 
    var reading = controller.GetCurrentReading();
}
```

Comment: I want to add more info from the documentation: *Gamepad supports any Xbox One certified or Xbox 360 compatible gamepad.*